# How to decode xml with xmlcoder?

Tags: swift, xml, rss, codable

i was making a simple rss reader as my first project but couldn't figure it out how to parse it. Data returns without a problem but can't parse it like json response, i tried xmlcoder to decode with codable protocol but that didn't work either. What am i doing wrong? Is it my struct? I am a little bit lost about xml.

My struct:

```
struct News: Codable {
    let version: String
    let channel: Channel

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version = "version"
        case channel = "channel"
    }
}

struct Channel: Codable {
    let title: String
    let link: String
    let channelDescription: String
    let generator: String
    let item: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case link = "link"
        case channelDescription = "description"
        case generator = "generator"
        case item = "item"
    }
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let title: String
    let link: String
    let itemDescription: String
    let enclosure: Enclosure
    let pubDate: String
    let guid: GUID
    let date: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case link = "link"
        case itemDescription = "description"
        case enclosure = "enclosure"
        case pubDate = "pubDate"
        case guid = "guid"
        case date = "date"
    }
}

struct Enclosure: Codable {
    let url: String
    let length: String?
    let type: TypeEnum

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url = "url"
        case length = "length"
        case type = "type"
    }
}

enum TypeEnum: String, Codable {
    case imageJPEG = "image/jpeg"
    case imageJpg = "image/jpg"
    case imagePNG = "image/png"
}

struct GUID: Codable {
    let isPermaLink: String
    let text: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isPermaLink = "isPermaLink"
        case text = "text"
    }
}
```

Url code:

```
func getDataFrom(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: Error?)->()) {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let download = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, error)
    }
    download.resume()
}

func getData() {
    getDataFrom(url: URL(string: "http://www.rssmix.com/u/12512309/rss.xml")!) { data, error in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        let decoder = XMLDecoder()
        decoder.shouldProcessNamespaces = true
        do {
            let note = try decoder.decode(News.self, from: data)
            print(note)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>News</title>
      <link>http://www.rssmix.com/</link>
      <description>This feed was created by mixing existing feeds from various sources.</description>
      <generator>RSSMix</generator>
      <item>
         <title>Animaniacs' 10 Best Educational Songs, Ranked</title>
         <link>https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2559082/animaniacs-best-educational-songs-ranked</link>
         <description>&lt;p&gt;The Animaniacs are back and more colorful than ever, so there's no better time to look back at the trio's best educational songs.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
         <enclosure url="https://img.cinemablend.com/quill/7/7/7/7/5/3/777753a254515e18c686dad2db5ad075b571d955.jpg" length="127057" type="image/jpg" />
         <pubDate>Mon, 23 Nov 2020 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
         <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2559082/animaniacs-best-educational-songs-ranked</guid>
         <dc:date>2020-11-23T13:00:00Z</dc:date>
      </item>
```

Comment: Maybe better to try the built in XMLParser instead

Comment: What is `XMLDecoder`? From where? Is there an `error` thrown? What's wrong?

Comment: Is error appears in `catch`? What it contains?

Comment: @Andrew I changed my struct and keys but doesnt work either. 

keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "@version", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "@version", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No attribute or element found for key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"@version\", intValue: nil) (\"@version\").", underlyingError: nil)

Comment: @Larme 
This is the library i used https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: `case version = "@version"` Why the `@`? I don't see it in your XML.

Comment: Oh, i used xml to json converter tool but I tried both with "@" and without, problem still remains.

Comment: I tried your code with your sample. I added closing tags: `</channel></rss>`, and then the error is different, you need to read it. In my case, I got an issue about `text`, in `GUID` because in `<guid isPermaLink="false">https://...</guid>` there is NO `text`. tag. After removing it, I got an issue about the `date`, to quickly "fix it and see more", I changed it as a `String`, let's do the `dateDecodingStrategy` later, and then I decoded correctly. Once it's done, let's continue fixing the different parts (`date`, `text`). But that's your part to do. You tried to do too much at once.

Comment: For the `text`, it needs to be in the `CodingKeys`: `case text = ""`, see the sample https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder#coding-key-value-intrinsic Do it step by step. Make progress by progress and READ the error messages. The rest is up to you. Do not hesitate to come back with specific error, but give the error (not only in comment), show tries, etc, read the README.md/docs. For instance, I never used that lib, but make some research and reading (reading errors and homepage of the pod).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally decode it after just changing the case text = "text" with this

```
struct GUID: Codable {
    let isPermaLink: String
    let text: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isPermaLink = "isPermaLink"
        case text = ""
    }
}
```

Many thanks to @Larme